# Publish GitHub Android Library to Maven Central

Tags: android, maven, gradle, sonatype, bintray

I work for 2 days to deploy my github library [**CircularImageView**](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) in maven central to use it with the gradle dependence like this:

```
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.0'
```

I followed this tutorial to the letter : [Publish an aar file to jCenter with Gradle](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/gradle-jcenter-publish) but there is nothing to do I can't access my Library that way.

**Please help me to know what I did wrong..**

Link :

- Bintray Repos : https://bintray.com/lopspower/maven/com.mikhaellopez%3Acircularimageview/view
- Sonatype Issue : https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-18203

**Edit : 10/14/2015**

To **Finally Sync all with Maven Central** in **Step 16.** of [tutorial](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/gradle-jcenter-publish) you need a **User token password**. How do I get that?

Bintray answer :

> Hi, The "User token password" is not taken from Bintray, it can be found in your Maven Central account. Please see further information on syncing with Maven here: https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_syncingartifactswithmavencentral.html Regards Bintray Team

Finally, it isn't clear but the "User token password" actually corresponds to the **password of your Sonatype account**. Now the project is **normally syncronise**, however **I still can't access the project**:

> Failed to resolve: com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.0

Comment: Check out this great [tutorial](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en)

Comment: Thank you @SandroMachado your solution is a very nice alternantive but I want to acces to my library without change the repositories of the user

Comment: you do not really need to publish to maven-central any more - jcenter is now the default for android projects and IMHO totally sufficient

Comment: You are right @ligi but my problem was actually a module name problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can see all the library in bintray [HERE](http://jcenter.bintray.com/).
I realized that my library was well but with a different path.

Indeed, in Android Studio **module name** is very important. So I renamed "**CircularImageView-Library**" in "**circularimageview**". I again syncronise with the new version and now it works.

I can acces to my library with gradle like :

```
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.1'
```

I edit the tutorial: https://github.com/lopspower/gradle-jcenter-publish